# Yarn v2 and Cocopods: node_modules folders doesn't exist

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, yarn-v2

I have upgraded `Yarn` to `v2`. I see that there is no `node_modules` folder anymore. But my `Podfile` is still looking for it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node_modules` are unavailable with default Yarn 2 PnP install strategy. But you can change this, add the line below to your `.yarnrc.yml` file to change install strategy from PnP to `node_modules`:

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```